# Credits for data storage - snowflake stages

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is a Snowflake account charged for data stored in both Internal and External stages? Yes or No.

I think this is tricky. I think it is No. My understanding/opinion is that Snowflake bills you for Internal stages obviously but for External Stages I am not sure if Snowflake bills you for storage or Cloud providers(AWS/Azure/GCP) bill you.
According to the definition a named external stage is a database object created in a schema. This object stores the URL to files in cloud storage, the settings used to access the cloud storage account, and convenience settings such as the options that describe the format of staged files. So when we create an external stage it is a pointer to the external cloud storage location. And so technically speaking there shouldn't a data storage cost for external stages.

But if the answer to the above question is Yes, I am a little confused. Wouldn't that be a double charge? S3 bucket is already charged and now creating a stage and pointing to that S3 bucket, Snowflake also charges you.

Comment: The cloud host bills you for storage in external stages. There are no storage charges for external stages billed through Snowflake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Greg mentioned, Snowflake only charges you for internal stages, details at the following link:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/credits.html#viewing-data-usage-for-your-account

To learn more about internal stages (user, table, and named), you can review the following link:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-create-stage.html